# How to use ViewHolder if I do not want to use butterknife

Tags: android, butterknife

I saw from an example that I can use ViewHolder with butterknife this way

```
static class ViewHolder {

    @Bind(R.id.device_name) TextView name;
    @Bind(R.id.device_address) TextView address;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}
```

If I do not want to use butterknife, how would i do so to attain the same effect of binding?

Answer (score 3):

Your solution:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView address;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        name = view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
        address = view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
    }
}
```

Comment: So may you accept my solution? However, that's basic knowledge you able to read from Google docs.